# My visa was rejected. Now I want to go for just 3 months to study

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, study

I was going to do a year abroad in the UK. My Tier 4 visa was rejected because I couldn't prove I have enough money. So I talked to the University in the UK to see if they could accept me for just one semester and they agreed and sent me a letter with an unconditional offer.

I checked and for 3 months I don't need a visa but I'm scared that they (Immigration) won't allow me to enter because I have a visa rejection.

Comment: Please add your nationality as this can be important. Also, even if you don't need a visa, you may still need to be able to prove you have enough money to support yourself while you are in the UK.

Comment: Last i was a student, and that was not long ago, a semester was longer than 3 months

Comment: The problem is less having a visa rejection than with being denied entry for the same reason as the visa rejection.

Comment: I think posting the refusal notice, with personal information blacked out, would be helpful. If the problem was just not enough money for a year, but sufficient for 3 months, you may be OK just taking the same documents with you. If there were other problems, that is less likely to work.